# Why is opacity not added to divs that are added?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having that problem that opacity is not added to tfrhe selected divs.

Here do I have a fine working example what I am trying to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/PRZ5J/13/

Here have I added the code from the first example with some other Jquery:
http://jsfiddle.net/gDChA/74/

The problem is that the added input field and its divs does not have the same function and opacity as the first example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the "live" function in jquery to ensure that newly created elements have any event listeners you set up.  In this case, instead of applying the `.click` listener to all the color squares, you would want to use a `.live` click event. e.g.

```
$('.blackDiv,.blueDiv,.redDiv').live("click", (clickopa));
```

and that will get you your event back.  I did a little tweaking of the function but this should work for you.

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z5qeX/)